# TimescaleDB upserts vs. InfluxDB writes: functionality and performance

Tags: postgresql, influxdb, timescaledb

TimescaleDB has some attractive and compelling benchmarks against influxDB, especially for high cardinality (which is our case). However as I understand it, there's a big assumption in the equivalence of functionality involved in the benchmarks:

**This may be considered as a limitation**, but writes in InfluxDB are designed in a way that there can be only a single `timestamp` + `tag keys` combination (`series` in influx terminology) associated with a `field`. This means that when writing twice the same combination `timestamp` + `tag keys` with a different `field value` every time, influxDB will only keep the last one. So it does overwrite by default, and one cannot have duplicated entries for a given `timestamp` + `tag keys` + `field`.

On the other hand, TimescaleDB allows multiple `timestamp` + `tag keys` + `field values` entries (although they would not be called this in TimescaleDB terminology), just like PostgreSQL would. If you want uniqueness you'll have to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination of tags.

This is where the problems start: if you actually want that "multiple entries for a tags combination" functionality, then TimescaleDB is the solution because influxDB simply does not do it. But on the opposite, if you want to compare TimescaleDB with influxDB you need to set up TimescaleDB to match the functionality of InfluxDB, which means using `UNIQUE` constraint and `UPSERT` (`ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` syntax of PostgreSQL). In my opinion, not doing so is making one of the following assumptions:

- The dataset will not have duplicated values, it is impossible for a timestamp/value pair to be  updated
- InfluxDB writes are equivalent to TimescaleDB inserts, which is not true, if I understood correctly.

My problem is that our use case involves overwrites, and I would guess many other use cases would. We have implemented a performance evaluation of our own, writing batches of 10k rows, time  ordered, for about 100k "tags" combinations (that is 2 tags+timestamp as a `UNIQUE` constraint) using `UPSERT`, and the performance drops pretty fast and is nowhere near that of InfluxDB.

Am I missing something here? Anyone has experience with using `UPSERT` with TimescaleDB at a large scale? Is there a way to mitigate this issue? Or is TimescaleDB simply not a good solution for our use case?

Thanks!

Comment: Heavy overwrites - particularly overwrites for non-recent data - are not a good use case for either Timescale or Influx. They're both optimized for appends. You may want to consider using just Postgres (or MySQL)

Comment: Hi @MichaelMullany, thank you for your comment. My use case is not particularly heavy on overwrites, it just has some and therefore needs to rely on some UPSERT functionality with TimescaleDB. But maybe there's a more efficient way to do this than with an UPSERT statement. Like, querying for existing keys and dropping them before a regular INSERT, or adding an insertion time column, doing the INSERT, then dropping rows where COUNT > 1 and insertion time is not the latest.